# How to generate PyKnow Rule dynamically?

Tags: python

I want to generate pyknow rules dynamically
instead of

```
class RuleEngine(KnowledgeEngine):
    @Rule(AS.light << Light(color='yellow'))
    def accept(self, light):
        print(light['color'])
```

something like

```
class RuleEngine(KnowledgeEngine):
    def accept(self, light):
        print(light['color'])

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.generate_rule(**data, self.accept)
```

data structure:

```
{'rule1': {color='green'}, 'rule2': {color='red'}
```